# Cannot play youtube videos on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: sound, firefox, video, google-chrome, flash

I have both Firefox and Chrome with both having the Flash plugin installed.  On Chrome, the Pepper Flash plugin is installed.  The behavior of the problem is exactly the same on both Firefox and Chrome; the video will play  for about 12 seconds without any audio and then stops.

I would appreciate any help with this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although similar, the pepper flash that comes with chrome is different than the one that is installed from the repos (adobe-flashplugin, or sth like that).

I know there is a way to tell firefox to use chrome's but I've never looked into that so not sure if that is your case.

Sadly when it comes to flash I think other than checking you are in the latest version there isn't much you can do. In this situation it sounds like the problem is only present for flash items on the browser.

With more info then more people can jump in.